# Swap nav and div vertically uing CSS only

Tags: html, css

So I have a `<nav>` in my `<header>` tag and just below it I have a `<div>` which shows the date. Now the problem is, my design is in such a way that I cannot put the `<div>` for the date inside my `<header>`. However since I'm working with a responsive design I have to swap the `<nav>` and the date `<div>` when on smaller screen resolutions.

I have read around S.O and I have seen several fixes using CSS for swapping 2 `<div>`s but I cannot get them to work with my code. I have no idea how to get around this to be honest and all the help is really appreciated. Here's the code snippet:

```
<header>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" title="Site Name" alt="logo">
    </div>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Day</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Week</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Month</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">From-To</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<div id="date">
    <p>Monday 09/03/15 16:16</p>
</div>
```

Edit:
As requested here's the fix I tried to implement but in vain.

**HTML**

```
<div class="swapHack">
    <header>
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" title="Site Name" alt="logo">
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Day</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Week</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Month</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">From-To</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="date">
        <p>Monday 09/03/15 16:16</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.swapHack{
      display:table;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .#date {
      display: table-header-group;
    }

    .nav {
      display: table-footer-group;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you move your Nav element outside of your Header element so it is between the Header and the date Div?

Comment: @IMI Unfortunately no. The design has both the logo and nav on the sam header. And then the date is just below to the left with some fancy design structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested swap does work. You had some errors in your css. You need to remove the period "`.`" before `nav` and `#date` in your css.

```css
.swapHack{
      display:table;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #date {
      display: table-header-group;
    }

    nav {
      display: table-footer-group;
    }
```

```html
<div class="swapHack>"
    <header>
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" title="Site Name" alt="logo" />
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Day</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Week</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Month</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">From-To</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="date">
        <p>Monday 09/03/15 16:16</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I checked out your site css and you may need to use `.swapHack {padding-top: 55px; position: relative;}` and `#logo {background-color: #374461;position: absolute;top: 0;}` in your mobile style to get your logo positioned at the top of the page above the date.